# Cordova Build fails on OS X with EACCES & ENOENT

Tags: ios, node.js, macos, cordova

I recently started building iOS apps using Cordova and I’ve hit a roadblock. After installing nodeJS, git and cordova (with sudo), I created my first app in the Documents folder of my user account.

The first run went perfectly. Everything worked, and adding my dev account to Xcode helped my app to run on the device. I decided I’d spice things up a bit by adding a “before_prepare” hook called `001_c.js` in `<appName>/hooks/before_prepare folder`. This is how the hook begins:

```
//This is where nodeJS exists
#!/usr/local/bin node

console.log("Changing config");

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var rootdir = process.argv[2];

//and so on
```

When I now build the app, I get this error:

> pc295786:master kellster$ cordova build ios Running command:
>   /Users/kellster/documents/apps/master/hooks/before_prepare/001_c.js
>   /Users/kellster/documents/apps/master Error: spawn ***EACCES***
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
>       at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1155:11)
>       at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:988:9)
>       at Object.exports.spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:104:31)
>       at runScriptViaChildProcessSpawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:188:23)
>       at runScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:131:16)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:114:20
>       at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)

To troubleshoot, I changed the first line of the hook script from

```
#!/usr/local/bin node
```

to

```
#! node
```

(Because this worked on Windows. `node` was in global scope). But, this resulted in an ENOENT error:

> pc295786:master kellster $ cordova build ios Running command:
>   /Users/kellster/documents/apps/master/hooks/before_prepare/001_c.js
>   /Users/kellster/documents/apps/master Error: Hook failed with error
>   code ***ENOENT***:
>   /Users/kellster/documents/apps/master/hooks/before_prepare/001_c.js
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:194:23
>       at _rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:797:24)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:823:30
>       at Promise.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:1035:31)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:741:41)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
>       at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
>       at startup (node.js:129:16)

**How do I get this to build?** I’d appreciate any suggestions I could try.

---

*Some things to note:*

1. (In my desperation, ) I tried running the following commands, because the "EACCES" type of error. But none of them seemed to have any kind of effect on the result. The build was still failing.

> ```
> sudo chmod 777 “/Users/kellster/documents/apps/master"
> sudo chmod 777 “/usr/local/lib”
> sudo chmod 777 "/usr/local/bin/"
> chmod 777 "/Users/kellster/documents/apps/master/platforms/"
> sudo chmod a+rwx "/Users/kellster/Documents/apps/Master/hooks/before_prepare/001_c.js"
> sudo chmod a+rwx "/Users/kellster/Documents/apps/Master/"
> sudo chown -R kellster /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
> ```

2) Node is installed in

> /usr/local/bin

Comment: does `sudo cordova build ios` work? That'll at least rule out access permissions as the the cause...

Comment: Nope @DaveAlden. It does not. Tried that as well

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Old answer:      #!/usr/local/bin node  ->  better #!/usr/bin/env node

Updated answer: do not use spaces for referencing node executable instead use:

```
     #!/usr/local/bin/node
```

Also chmod your script: For example:

```
      chmod 777 hooks/before_prepare/onde.js
```

where onde.js it is your script. If you're on Mac(my case) or Linux, then your .js must on chmod 777 to avoid EACCES errors.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but there is no `env` folder in `bin` folder. When I run a change directory command, I get this `-bash: cd: /usr/bin/env: Not a directory`

Comment: Just because  this is not a folder, just an environment reference in your script. Anyway, keeping #!/usr/local/bin node and chmod 777 you script should work. Try env in your console, you should see what paths and vars are defined :)

Comment: I have tested with /usr/local/bin/node  and it is working. No spaces in path. cordova build ios
Running command: /Users/mainframe/Desktop/hello/hooks/before_prepare/a.js /Users/mainframe/Desktop/hello
Changing config

Comment: Thanks! changed the first line to `/usr/local/bin/node` from `/usr/local/bin node`. Also ran `chmod`. Then it worked. Please update this answer so that it might help a poor soul (such as myself)

Comment: chmod fixed it for me. No need to give write access, though. `find hooks -iname "*.js" -exec chmod a+x {} \;`

Comment: I tried `chmod`, it didn't do the trick for me, I'm still getting this error.